# NpgSql Call function / routine

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Given the following Postgresql routine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkemailexists (emailaddress text) RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
#print_strict_params on
DECLARE
existsCount int;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO STRICT existsCount
        FROM usercontacts WHERE usercontacts.contactaddress = emailAddress;
    IF existsCount > 0 THEN RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

And the following .NET (Npgsql) block:

```
 public bool EmailExists(string email)
        {
            using (var conn = Connection)
            {
                conn.Open();
                using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("checkemailexists", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text ,"my@email.com");
                    var ret = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }
```

I keep getting the following error

`PostgresException: 42883: function checkemailexists(emailAddress => text) does not exist`

I'm a total newb to postgres and I'm not being very successful finding a relevant answer searching.

Can you please help me understand why this function cannot be found when I try to call it?

SELECT version();

`PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit`

.NET Core

Npgsql 3.1.9

Thank you!

Comment: your calling syntax proved an aid to me, so take comfort in your detour. It wasn't *all* for naught...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welp... Case Sensitive is the phrase of the day.

emailAddress != emailaddress

Answer (score -1):

PostgresException: 42883: function checkemailexists(emailAddress => text) does not exist

**ANS=>Postgre is case sensitive, so always check proper function name & parameters name**