# Can't read data from Postgres stored function with C# / .Net & Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a Postgres function that works as intended within Dbeaver

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getallusersv2()
 RETURNS SETOF users
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

begin
    RETURN QUERY
      SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users ORDER BY id;
    return;
END;
$function$;
```

However when attempting to call the function with Npgsql I dont get my expected result.

Heres the code I used to execute and read the data

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT getallusersv2()", conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

there is a method I have written that is supposed to map the results I get back to but I cant even get that far since I seem not to have any data to parse.

Upon debugging I noticed the following error:

`The field 'getallusersv2' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 16421). You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ.`

[debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQTJK.png)

But the thing that really sticks out is that there doesn't seem to be any data that is being returned. Instead it seems to be just an empty object named after the function being called.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after banging my head for the last few hours, I just figured it out.  Apparently, you have to write the `SELECT` as follows `SELECT * FROM getallusersv2()`

I will leave up the question just in case someone else is having the same issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200642/npgsql-call-function-routine). From what I can notice, there is no need to use `SELECT`. The name of the function seems to suffice.